# appAPI.openURL Issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: popup, popupwindow, crossrider, modal-popup

I am facing a Issue in appAPI.openURL parameter popup.

I expected popup parameter will open my URL as popup window. but it is popping under the main window. which is not my requirement.

I need to open my window as popup (modal popup) but not as pop under.

this is how i am doing it

```
appAPI.openURL({
url: href,
where: "popup",
focus: false
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a modal window/popup has [limited support](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm) by browsers/JavaScript and is less likely to work/be supported cross browser.

The nearest cross browser option you can achieve is to specify the *where* property of [appAPI.openURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-openURL) as **window** to open a popup window that is not modal.

```
appAPI.openURL({
  url: href,
  where: "window",
  focus: false
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: can you give any tips to debug background.js file. i am checking my installs for this i am sending a post request from background.js with my installid, and i am unable to get the request. @Shlomo

Answer (score 0):

```
    appAPI.openURL({
        url: href,
        where: "window",
        focus: true,
        height:window.screen.availHeight,
        width:window.screen.availWidth
    });
```

This opens a popup window above my browser.